# Buffons needle simulation using turtle. I can not get my if else statement to change the color of the needles?

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to recreate Buffon's needle simulation in python3 for a class. What I came up with seems to do a good job of estimating pi but I am having trouble with my if-else statement. What I want is to have the needles turn red if they intersect one of the black lines, and turn blue if they do not (see picture link). It seems to assign a color to a needle randomly, and I am not sure why this is. Help with this issue would be greatly appreciated! :)

[image: screenshot]

```
import math
import turtle
import random
from math import pi, cos, sin

def BuffonNeedles(numNeedles):

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    georgie = turtle.Turtle()

    wn.setworldcoordinates(-2, -2, 2, 2)

    georgie.up()
    georgie.goto(-2, 0)
    georgie.down()
    georgie.goto(2, 0)

    georgie.up()
    georgie.goto(-2, 1)
    georgie.down()
    georgie.goto(2, 1)

    numHit = 0

    for i in range(numNeedles):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        angle = random.random() * 180

        formula1 = float(math.sin(math.radians(angle)) / 2)
        point1 = y + formula1
        point2 = y - formula1

        if point1 >= 1 or point2 <= 0:
            numHit = numHit + 1
            georgie.color("red")

        else:
            georgie.color("blue")

        georgie.up()
        georgie.goto(x, y)
        georgie.right(angle)
        georgie.down()
        georgie.forward(1)

    pi = 2 * (numNeedles / numHit)
    wn.exitonclick()

    print(pi)
    return pi

BuffonNeedles(1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You need to check all four conditions concerning crossing the border. `Point1` and `Point2` could be on either side of either border.
- You calculate the center of the line and calculate the starting Y coordinate, but you're still using the X coordinate of the center point. This draws the line .5 from where it should be.
- Once you calculate the center point, draw each half from the center to clarify what's happening.

Try this code:

```
import math
import turtle
import random
from math import pi, cos, sin

def BuffonNeedles(numNeedles):

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    georgie = turtle.Turtle()

    wn.setworldcoordinates(-2, -2, 2, 2)

    georgie.up()
    georgie.goto(-2, 0)
    georgie.down()
    georgie.goto(2, 0)

    georgie.up()
    georgie.goto(-2, 1)
    georgie.down()
    georgie.goto(2, 1)

    numHit = 0

    for i in range(numNeedles):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        angle = random.random() * 180

        formula1 = float(math.sin(math.radians(angle)) / 2)
        print(formula1)
        point1 = y + formula1
        point2 = y - formula1

        if (point1 >= 1 and point2 <= 1) or (point1 >= 0 and point2 <= 0) \
        or (point2 >= 1 and point1 <= 1) or (point2 >= 0 and point1 <= 0):
            numHit = numHit + 1
            georgie.color("red")
        else:
            georgie.color("blue")
      
        # first half
        georgie.up()
        georgie.goto(x, y)
        georgie.setheading(angle)
        georgie.down()
        georgie.forward(.5)

        # second half
        georgie.up()
        georgie.goto(x, y)
        georgie.setheading(angle+180)
        georgie.down()
        georgie.forward(.5)

    pi = 2 * (numNeedles / numHit)
    wn.exitonclick()

    print(pi)
    return pi

BuffonNeedles(1000)
```

Output

[image: Needles]

Comment: ahh, I understand now! Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the needle position test is much simpler if you check for needles that fall between the lines instead of ones that don't:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random
from math import pi, sin, degrees

def buffonNeedles(numNeedles):

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-1, 1)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(3)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.backward(3)

    numHits = 0

    for _ in range(numNeedles):
        x, y = random(), random()
        angle = random() * pi

        yDelta = sin(angle) / 2

        if 0 < y + yDelta < 1 and 0 < y - yDelta < 1:
            turtle.color('blue')
        else:
            numHits += 1
            turtle.color('red')

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        turtle.setheading(degrees(angle))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(0.5)
        turtle.backward(1.0)

    return 2 * (numNeedles / numHits)

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 2, 2)
screen.tracer(False)

print(buffonNeedles(1000))

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

I also centered the coordinate system and simplified the code a bit.  This should have been even simpler using `turtle.radians()` to have just one system but unfortunately, `setworldcoordinates()` throws off the angle of turtle radians.